# Prompt for target window if one is not marked

Tags: tmux

I have a keybinding in tmux for swapping the current and marked (`prefix-m`) windows:

```
bind \ swap-window
```

Also, I have a different version that will ask me for the window to swap with:

```
bind \ command-prompt -p 'Swap with window:' 'swap-window -t %%'
```

I would like the first version to be used if there *is* a marked window, and the second version to be used if there is *not* a marked window.

Can this be done with tmux? I can't find a way to check whether there is a marked window.